# Render page after specific time Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/")));

const end = 1523548800*1000// 1523989800000;

console.log(end - date <= 0);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
const date = Date.now();
  if (end - date <= 0) {
    res.render("index");
  } else {
    res.render("cd");
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("App listening on port port!");
});
```

I want to allow a user to view `index page` after specific time before that when a user request for `index page` I want to show them another page. I am getting it as what I want but I am not satisfied with this can anyone suggest the better way.

Comment: Your code is buggy. you should call Date.now() inside the request handler middleware, else the date var is updated only once, when you run the server.

Comment: it was i using just for debugging process i made a change in question.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with this code?

Comment: i want to optimize it with promise or async await but don't know how

Comment: That's not optimizing, that's overengineering. You don't need promises for such a simple, and more importantly synchronous task.